# Unclear cloudformation template for cloudwatch agent for ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm going through the cloudformation template that installs cloudwatch agent on existing EC2 instances
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/solutions/AmazonCloudWatchAgent/ssm/ubuntu.template

The block from line 122-130

```
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Sub:
            - |
               #!/bin/bash
               wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb -O /tmp/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
               dpkg -i /tmp/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
               /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c ssm:${ssmkey} -s
               apt-get update -y
               apt-get  install -y python-pip
               easy_install --script-dir /opt/aws/bin  https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
               /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region} --configsets default
               /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
            - { ssmkey: !Ref SSMKey }
```

Once the `amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config` has been run it will automatically start sending the metrics to cloudwatch. What is the reason for all the subsequent steps for cfn?

Another block

```
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '22'
        ToPort: '22'
        CidrIp:
          Ref: SSHLocation
```

Since it is an existing vm I imagine it already has a security group attached to it and the goal would be to just install the cloudwatch agent. Why is it creating another security group and adding to the vm? Can I remove that section all together if I do not want the security group of existing vm tampered or modified?

I also see the wget link is hardcoded to amd64 arch. Is it correct to assume this template won't work on arm64 arch type since it has a different download link at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html

Comment: What do you mean existing VM? The userdata section you show only executes the first time the instance is created. This is a lot of separate questions.

Comment: Seems I mistook the template's purpose as installing cloudwatch agent on an existing vm. Is it actually for provisioning the instance plus agent install?